# How to pass an calculated image to other function in matlab and get the final result in another variable after executing some conditions?

Tags: matlab

For example like this i want to do

```
diff_bw_image=imabsdiff(nextimage,previmage);
imshow(diff_bw_img);
segment_image(diff_bw_image);
```

I want to call the the following function through the above calculated image

I want to store the final result in `final_image` after applying some conditions on the passed image to this function

```
function segment_image(diff_bw_image)
    final_image=zeros(240,360);
    for i=1 : 240
        for j=1: 360
            if(diff_bw_image(i,j)<=0.5(suppose))
                final_image(i,j)=0;
            else
                final_image(i,j)=1;
            end
        end
        imshow(final_image)
    end
end
```

Comment: please, format your code using code tags

Comment: @HrishabhPrajapati this seems like a very basic question about [functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/functions.html) inputs/outputs. You should spend some time reading the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify an [output argument](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html#examples) (`final_image`) for your function.

```
function final_image = segment_image(diff_bw_image)
    final_image=zeros(240,360);
    for i=1 : 240
        for j=1: 360
            if(diff_bw_image(i,j)<=0.5(suppose))
                final_image(i,j)=0;
            else
                final_image(i,j)=1;
            end
        end
        imshow(final_image)
    end
end
```

Then for any function that calls this, you will want to assign the output variable to another variable

```
final_image = segment_image(diff_bw_image)
```

Comment: Thank you Suever .